# Regular graph coloring conjecture

Tags: graph-theory

Almost all regular graphs with degree $k^2$ are $k+1$ colorable.

The near absence (finitude) of adjacent small cycles in random regular graphs as $N$ (the size of the graph) grows may help imply the truth, but any proof looks far away.
The conjecture is empirically true for $k=3$ (i.e. Almost all 9-regular graphs are 4 colorable).

Does this conjecture have a name, or better yet, is it true?

Comment: As N grows, the probability of the property being true approaches 1.  For 9-regular graphs, for example, N needs to be greater than about 125 for it to be likely to be 4 colorable.

Comment: The chromatic number of a random $d$-regular graph is $\Theta(d/\log d)$ a.s. See for example http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589569290070E

Comment: That appears to answer the question, so thank you.